# No sound plays from headphones on an MSI Wind u100 netbook

Tags: 11.10, sound

Just performed a fresh install and sound plays from the speakers but not from the headphones. No sound at all. If I pull the jack out, then push it in slightly, it works but sound plays from the speakers also.

```
    lspci | grep -i audio
    00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio            Controller (rev 02)
```

I am using an MSI Wind u100 netbook. F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in the same quandary, running ubuntu 11.10 I would plug in my headphones and the sound would stop from my speakers but no sound would emit from my headphones.  Below is a possible workaround that worked for me:

Left click on the upper right speaker/sound icon and then in the context menu that appears, click on sound settings at the bottom.

Now click on the "output" tab. Here you should see your audio device for output and at the very bottom a drop down that is labled "connector".

When I plug in my headphones, this drop down automatically changes to "Analog Headphones".  If I then click on the drop down menu and change this to be "Analog Speakers" without unplugging or changing anything else, the sound just starts to work again in my headphones.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I found that some laptops do not have a second option in that dropdown list. Try installing alsa-hda-dkms from the daily repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem in Oneiric on various laptops too.

Found a permanent solution:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install alsa-hda-dkms
```

Let me know if it works :)